# How to use CFNumberFormatterRoundingMode in Swift

Tags: swift

### How to use `CFNumberFormatterRoundingMode` in Swift?

`CFNumberFormatterRoundingMode` has many `case`

> kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling Round towards positive infinity.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor Round towards negative infinity.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown Round towards zero.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundUp Round away from zero.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven Round towards the nearest integer, or
>   towards an even number if equidistant.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfDown Round towards the nearest integer, or
>   towards zero if equidistant.
>
> kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp Round towards the nearest integer, or
>   away from zero if equidistant.

I calculation round `Decimal` with `NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:)`.
`NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:)` only have parameter for `NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode`.
`NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode` has a few `case`.

> case plain Round to the closest possible return value; when caught
>   halfway between two positive numbers, round up; when caught between
>   two negative numbers, round down.
>
> case down Round return values down.
>
> case up Round return values up.
>
> case bankers Round to the closest possible return value; when halfway
>   between two possibilities, return the possibility whose last digit is
>   even.

Can I use CFNumberFormatterRoundingMode in Swift?
Is there any alternative to `NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:)`?

#### Link

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfnumberformatterroundingmode?language=objc
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1412204-nsdecimalround
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/roundingmode-vau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFNumberFormatterRoundingMode` is meant to be used with `CFNumberFormatter`.

It would be more convenient to use `NumberFormatter` and set its `roundingMode` property which has the same options.

You use a number formatter to convert a number to a string (or visa-versa) using a specific `numberStyle` (such as decimal, currency, percent, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let f = NumberFormatter()
f.numberStyle = .decimal
f.maximumFractionDigits = 2
f.roundingMode = .down

f.string(from: Decimal(0.111) as NSNumber)
f.string(from: Decimal(-0.111) as NSNumber)

f.string(from: Decimal(0.116) as NSNumber)
f.string(from: Decimal(-0.116) as NSNumber)
```